# Can I use inequality in command-block testfor arguments?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know there is the basic `/testfor @a[score_HEALTH=1,team=red]` but I need the "less than" argument.

How can I denote inequality, as in `@a[score_health<20]` instead of `=20`?
when I do  `score_health<10` it just gives me an error.

Comment: did you even try `score_health<10` which is in your question title? if so what happens what what were you expecting to happen?

Comment: well... I just get an big fat error... I have been haveing problems woth command changing though so ill try that again. Thanks for your input!

Comment: if your getting an error could you also edit that into your question so not only do we know you tried something but we can see what may have gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you test for a score is to use = and min=. For example, `/testfor @a[score_health=20]` will testfor all players who's health is 20 or below. `/testfor @a[score_health_min=8]` will testfor all players who's health is 8 or more. To test if a player has 3 to 9 health you can do `/testfor @a[score_health_min=3,score_health=9]`. I hope this helps!

Links: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! i'm going to go test it. If it works you deserve $1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Comment: OMG U DESERVE `$1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` if i had that much i would give it to you. Heres the command i used,

Comment: It worked. ... ... ... ... Well i don't have the money but heres my command: `/testfor @a[score_health_min=1,score_health=19,team=red]` and   `/testfor @a[score_health_min=1,score_health=19,team=blue]` THAN YOU SO MUCH MY FRIENDS WILL LOVE THIS MINIGAME!!! `YOU ARE AWESOME`

Comment: it worked...my command: `/tp @a[score_health_min=1,score_health=19,team=red] and /tp @a[score_health_min=1,score_health=19,team=blue]` and it works so yeah! dont have da  money... @AoElite

Answer (score 1):

As of Minecraft 1.13, score arguments are specified using ranges

```
selector[scores={OBJECTIVE=min..max}]
```

Therefore, to select all players with "health" scores less than 10, do `@a[scores={health=..9}]`

Answer (score -1):

OK I'm so happy but thanks to AoElite i found the answer. here it is. `/testfor @a[score_health_min=3,score_health=9]` modify that and you have the ultimate minecraft team respawn/death command for command blocks.